# How do I get mysql user_id from php session?

Tags: php, mysql

In my code I use $user_id = $_SESSION["USER_ID"]; to get the users id that is valid. If I use echo function in PHP it displays the correct id but when I try to use it in query it says it is undefined.

I am using XAMPP with:
    PHP 7.1.27 , 7.2.16 , 7.3.3
    Apache 2.4.38
    MariaDB 10.1.38
    Perl 5.16.3
    OpenSSL 1.0.2r (UNIX only)
    phpMyAdmin 4.8.5

```
$user_id = $_SESSION["USER_ID"];

// Funkcija prebere oglase iz baze in vrne polje objektov

function get_oglasi(){
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE user_id= echo '$user_id'; ";
    $res = $conn->query($query);
    $oglasi = array();
    while($oglas = $res->fetch_object()){
        array_push($oglasi, $oglas);
    }
    return $oglasi;
}
```

I expect the output of $user_id = 17 and I get error that it is undefined. But if I try `<p>Opis: <?php echo $user_id;?></p>` I get correct number.

Comment: `$user_id` doesn't exist within `get_oglasi()`. See [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know what I was doing there... You resolved my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php you are not able read variable without Global declaring or send to function parameter.
Please set this session user_id like below code

```
 $user_id = $_SESSION["USER_ID"];

 function get_oglasi(){

 $user_id=$GLOBALS['user_id'];

 global $conn;
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE user_id='$user_id'; ";
 $res = $conn->query($query);
 $oglasi = array();
 while($oglas = $res->fetch_object()){
    array_push($oglasi, $oglas);
 }
return $oglasi;
}
```

Hopefully that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make $user_id  as global global $user_id; because You are using in function and it is define outside function.

Answer (score 0):

Or pass a parameter to a function then you will get the id inside the function
function get_oglasi($id)